# String functions do not work with ConcatenatedCorpusView Object

Tags: python, string, nltk

This is what I have right now:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
w = brown.words()
print w.lower()
```

But when I run it, it says

```
AttributeError: 'ConcatenatedCorpusView' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What the heck is going on and how can I fix this???

Answer (score 7):

`brown.words()` returns an iterable and not a `str`. Refer the [manual](http://www.nltk.org/data.html)

[`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) is a `str` attribute

you need to do

```
for w in brown.words():
    print w.lower()
```